# System.Windows.Forms.Timer Tick interval shorter than defined interval

Tags: powershell, timer

I am developing a Powershell script using System.Windows.Forms to monitor and process contents of a folder. To automatically check the contents of a folder i used System.Windows.Forms.Timer with an interval of 2000ms. Each Tick the function Timer_Tick is invoked, which in its turn invokes another function.

When starting the script the functions are immediately invoked dozens of times in a second and then slows down. I added some `Write-Host` statements clarify the issue. After starting the script
the WaitForStart and Timer_Tick functions are invoked multiple times per second. My expectation was that the functions would have been invoked (approx.) once every 2 seconds.

```
Printen van dossier naar hotfo
Form load
Timer Tick + 17:03:369637
Wait for Start  + 17:03:369637
Timer Tick + 17:03:369735
Wait for Start  + 17:03:369735
Timer Tick + 17:03:369794
Wait for Start  + 17:03:369794
Timer Tick + 17:03:369882
Wait for Start  + 17:03:369882
Timer Tick + 17:03:369970
Wait for Start  + 17:03:369970
Timer Tick + 17:03:370009
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370009
Timer Tick + 17:03:370057
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370057
Timer Tick + 17:03:370145
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370145
Timer Tick + 17:03:370204
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370204
Timer Tick + 17:03:370282
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370282
Timer Tick + 17:03:370360
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370360
Timer Tick + 17:03:370448
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370448
Timer Tick + 17:03:370546
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370546
Timer Tick + 17:03:370614
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370614
Timer Tick + 17:03:370673
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370673
Timer Tick + 17:03:370741
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370741
Timer Tick + 17:03:370829
Wait for Start  + 17:03:370829
Timer Tick + 17:03:370907
```

The powershell script

```
Param (
        # Define parameters below, each separated by a comma

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Dossierfolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Hotfolder
)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$nl = "`r`n"

$font_small = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,12'
$font_large = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,18'

$LocalPrinterForm                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$LocalPrinterForm.ClientSize        = '500,300'
$LocalPrinterForm.text              = "LazyAdmin - PowerShell GUI Example"
$LocalPrinterForm.BackColor         = "#ffffff"


$Heading                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Heading.text                       = "OVD Hotfolder printer"
$Heading.AutoSize                   = $true
$Heading.width                      = 25
$Heading.height                     = 10
$Heading.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,20)
$Heading.Font                       = $font_large

$DossierFolderLabel                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$DossierFolderLabel.text            = "Dossier folder :"
$DossierFolderLabel.AutoSize        = $true
$DossierFolderLabel.width           = 25
$DossierFolderLabel.height          = 10
$DossierFolderLabel.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,50)
$DossierFolderLabel.Font            = $font_small

$HotFolderLabel                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$HotFolderLabel.text                = "Hot folder :"
$HotFolderLabel.AutoSize            = $true
$HotFolderLabel.width               = 25
$HotFolderLabel.height              = 10
$HotFolderLabel.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,70)
$HotFolderLabel.Font                = $font_small

$StatusLabel                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$StatusLabel.text                   = "STATUS :"
$StatusLabel.AutoSize               = $true
$StatusLabel.width                  = 25
$StatusLabel.height                 = 10
$StatusLabel.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,100)
$StatusLabel.Font                   = $font_small

$ProgressIndicator                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressIndicator.Minimum          = 1
$ProgressIndicator.Maximum          = 25
$ProgressIndicator.Value            = 12
$ProgressIndicator.Step             = 1
$ProgressIndicator.width            = 450
$ProgressIndicator.height           = 20
$ProgressIndicator.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,140)

$Logging                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Logging.MultiLine                  = $true
$Logging.width                      = 450
$Logging.height                     = 100
$Logging.ScrollBars                 = "vertical";
$Logging.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,160)

$LocalPrinterForm.controls.AddRange(@($Heading,$DossierFolderLabel,$HotFolderLabel,$StatusLabel,$ProgressIndicator, $Logging))

Write-Host "Printen van dossier naar hotfolder"

<# Start with only when hotfolder is empty #>
$hotfolderfiles = Get-ChildItem $Hotfolder -Filter *.pdf 
$hotfoldernumfiles = $hotfolderfiles.Count 

if ($hotfoldernumfiles -ne 0) {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Hotfolder is niet, leeg hotfolder "' + 
        $Hotfolder + '" en start hotfolderprint opnieuw','Waarschuwing','Ok')
    exit
}

<# Set timer #>
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 2000

<# Processing each interval #>
Function WaitForStart {
    
    <# $HotFolderLabel.Text = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"#>
    Write-Host "Wait for Start " + $DossierFolderLabel.Text
    $Logging.AppendText($HotFolderLabel.Text + $nl )
}

<# Start Timer on Load #>
Function Form_Load {
    $timer.Start()
    Write-Host "Form load"
}

<# Interval Handling #>
Function Timer_Tick {
    $DossierFolderLabel.Text = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ssffff"
    Write-Host "Timer Tick" + $DossierFolderLabel.Text
    WaitForStart
}

$LocalPrinterForm.Add_Load({Form_Load})
$timer.add_tick({Timer_Tick})

[void]$LocalPrinterForm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer is not destroyed when closing the window. Therefore the events from the timer are queued. Every time the application is started, the queued events are handled resulting in an event storm. Then after eacht start of the application an extra timer is started. So with an interval of 2000 seconds, at least one event every seconds is received.

The solution is simple;

Add a `$timer.Dispose()` as the last line in the script as a catch-all when the script is killed. To dispose the timer when the Form is closed in a controlled way, add a function to handle de close event of the form

```
Function Form_Closing {
    $timer.Stop();  
    Write-Host "Form unload"
}
```

And register the function to handle the `Add_Closing` event.

```
$LocalPrinterForm.Add_Closing({Form_Closing})
```